# xcode 6 - symbols not found for architecture i386 (zbar)

Tags: ios, xcode, zbar

I have a project which uses the zbar-sdk (a barcode scanning library).

After updating my machine to xcode 6 I am having some trouble.
Please help me solve this.

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZBarReaderViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MenuListViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: add architectures  i386 armv6 armv7 armv7s in Target> Build Settings > Architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to import AVFoundation and AudioToolbox frameworks and also set  i386 armv6 armv7 armv7s architectures needed for running the libraries